# is that a good way to gather smart contract action data in backend with Demux.js？

Tags: smart-contract, dapp, data-storage, dapp-development

there is a *Bill* functionality in my DApp, which need gather millions of EOS action data to make up a token transfer data for front end to display.

the question is, it takes quite a long time. if it is executed in client side, every time the user refresh, the Dapp regathers again and again.

so I wanna establish a server to do the stuff, but as we know , DApp is decentralized, it bases on chain, not on traditional backend. idk whether it is ok to do so.

need advice, thanks.

Comment: not sure what you're asking. please try to rephrase or explain in more details what the problem is and why you think demux might solve it.

Comment: @AmiHeines   is it ok now?

Answer (score 2):

Demux is intended for use when there is s lot of data that you want to save to the blockchain but not necessarily to RAM. RAM is an expensive resource and only needed if the dApp needs access to the data. Historical data is saved on disk in the blockchain log files and demux captures it to a database of your choosing.

Then you have the convenience of a client server app with a traditional db guarantied to be backed by the blockchain.

Comment: many thanks, and in a word, your answer to my question is 'yes'?

Comment: Yes, demux is the way to implement this.